# Problem drawing Bezier curves in Inkscape 1.2.1

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

I am trying to draw Bezier curves using Inkscape 1.2.1 (9c6d41e, 2022-07-14).

For some reason, the path produced has straight angles, see the attached picture.

I did not have this problem before, and re-installing Inkscape did not help...

What can I do to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

[image: Right angles]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are you clicking and dragging to create Bézier handles?  If you just click and don't drag, you will get straight lines. This is how the tool is supposed to work.  [see example](https://imgur.com/QZqCCVt)

Comment: If you are looking for automatic curves, there are spiro and b-spline options in the controls bar along the top, but these are not technically Bézier curves.